# Same file: different when opened with notepad vs. wordpad

Tags: file, notepad, wordpad

Was accessing a file in a code with both C# and C++. When file is opened in notepad it looks like this (one integer at left and the rest of numbers are double):

[image]

But the same file when opened with WordPad looks like this (one integer next to each double):

[image]

Why do they look different?

Comment: Why do you think it's a `C#` question? Are you capable to provide hex-dump of that file content?

Comment: Your line endings are incorrect. In Windows the line endings should be `\r\n`, on Unix and the like `\n` and on apple's systems it used to be `\r`. edit: corrected the apple's systems information.

Comment: @Sinatr The file looked the same (in both Notepad & WordPad) when I was writing it with only C++, but after I accessed it with both C# and C++, it looks different in Notepad and WordPad. How can I provide hex-dump?

Comment: @lared Apple uses \n too (\r was in the old days)

Comment: @rmuller you're right, sorry for introducing wrong information.

Comment: Hex-dump is easy to obtain with file managers (they have hex-viewer build-in usually). [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8n4pQ.png) is one from `Far Manager`. As you can see line end symbol (in windows) is `0xD 0xA`, you can use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) to ensure it's proper in current operation system. You can add `C#` exporting part and tag question as [tag:C#] if you need further help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the way that newlines are encoded in your file. Windows recognizes a newline as consisting of two characters (`\r\n`) whereas some other operating systems, namely Unix-based ones, use only `\n` or `\r`. WordPad is smart enough to recognize both newline types, but Notepad is not.

Answer (score 1):

Because notepad and Wordpad use different ways to read out files, apperantly this file is written in a way that both read it differently...

Answer (score 1):

Because Notepad and WorkPad understand \r\n differently

Answer (score 1):

Notepad and WordPad treat "new line" differently - one accepts just `\n`, another requires `\r\n` to recognize "new line" (and some would be ok with `\n\r`).

Similar goes for many other editors. I.e. if your try to open the file in Visual Studio it is likely to ask something like "Do you want to convert Unix new lines to Windows new lines".

If you are writing file with C# use `WriteLine` rather than manually adding `\n` or at least use [Envirnment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write "new line" to stream.

Similarly in C++ you can write "\r\n" instead of just "\n" if you must open file in Notepad or other editor that requires such sequence (most editors/viewers would be ok with either).